# Identifying Number of Values in a Specific Range

Tags: r, range, grouping

I'm relatively new to R and had a question about identifying the number of values which fall in a certain range.

I have a data table with column names as cell type (20 cell types) and then row names of 23000 genes and their methylation values (between 0 and 1) for each of the cell types. I've provided a sample of the dataset below (I hope it is clear!)

```
                 MCF-7     T47D     Kuramochhi   CAOV4      JHOS4
cg00964109 0.03425448 0.042629239 0.08461351 0.04095205 0.039999  
cg00967316 0.44065041 0.800911854 0.35689046 0.63291139 0.812005277  
cg00968475 0.64207018 0.910031909 0.06120248 0.84703547 0.084849946
```

What I would like to do is run a loop (or an easier way if possible!) to identify the number of genes with methylation values that fall in the following ranges: 0-0.0999, 0.1-0.1999, 0.2-0.29999 etc up to 0.9-1 for each cell type. I would also like to do a similar analysis (i.e number of genes with a methylation value that falls in the aforementioned ranges) for the entire data table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
R> apply(Data,2,function(x){
      table(cut(x,seq(0,1,.1),right=F))
  })
          MCF-7 T47D Kuramochhi CAOV4 JHOS4
[0,0.1)      99  105        102   103   100
[0.1,0.2)    99   90        116   105   102
[0.2,0.3)    98  103         93    92    97
[0.3,0.4)   108   91         91    93   105
[0.4,0.5)   103  114        104   101   107
[0.5,0.6)   100  111         77    97   105
[0.6,0.7)    98   89        110   103   102
[0.7,0.8)    97  100        110    81   109
[0.8,0.9)   106  112         90   110    94
[0.9,1)      92   85        107   115    79
```

---

**Data:**

```
set.seed(123)
Data <- matrix(runif(5000),ncol=5,
               dimnames=list(
                 paste0("gene_",1:1000),
                 c('MCF-7','T47D','Kuramochhi',
                   'CAOV4','JHOS4')))
```

Answer (score -1):

This should at least get you started:

```
x <- read.table(text="MCF-7     T47D     Kuramochhi   CAOV4      JHOS4
cg00964109 0.03425448 0.042629239 0.08461351 0.04095205 0.039999  
cg00967316 0.44065041 0.800911854 0.35689046 0.63291139 0.812005277  
cg00968475 0.64207018 0.910031909 0.06120248 0.84703547 0.084849946")

apply(x, 1, function(value) length(which(value <= 0.0999)))
apply(x, 1, function(value) length(which(value >= 0.1 & value <= 0.1999)))
apply(x, 1, function(value) length(which(value >= 0.2 & value <= 0.2999)))
```

etc.